# Signed integers' undefined behavior and Apple Secure Coding Guide

Tags: c, integer, overflow, integer-overflow

[Apple Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/SecureCodingGuide.pdf) says the following (page 27):

> Also, any bits that overflow past the length of an integer variable (whether signed or unsigned) are dropped.

However, regards to signed integer overflow [C standard (89)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) says:

> An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.

and

> If an exception occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not representable), the behavior is undefined.

Is the Coding Guide wrong? Is there something here that I don't get? I am not convinced myself that Apple **Secure** Coding Guide could get this wrong.

Comment: Who are you going to trust, the C standard or some intern in a company that sells shiny boxes?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I just need a strong second opinion to be sure that something Apple publishes in their `Secure` coding guide is wrong. It could be that i'm erroneously interpreting the C standard.

Comment: Does Pascal's 34k rep or ouah's 63k or my 89k count as a "strong second opinion"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this example:

```
1 << 32
```

If we assume 32-bit `int`, C clearly says it is undefined behavior. Period.

But any implementation can define this undefined behavior.

`gcc` for example says (while not very explicit in defining the behavior):

> GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 only to treat certain aspects of signed '<<' as undefined, but this is subject to change.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

I don't know for clang but I suspect that as for `gcc`, the evaluation of an expression like `1 << 32` would give no surprise (that is, evaluate to `0`).

But even if it is defined on implementations running in Apple operating systems, a portable program should not make use of expressions that invoke undefined behavior in the C language.

**EDIT:** I thought the Apple sentence was dealing only with bitwise `<<` operator. It looks like it's more general and in that case for C language, they are utterly wrong.

Comment: +1 Especially like the concern about portability.  That really is the crux of this question.

Comment: `1 << 31` also has undefined behavior on 32-bit platforms, which is much less intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a second opinion, from a static analyzer [described](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1125) as detecting undefined behavior:

```
int x;

int main(){
  x = 0x7fffffff + 1;
}
```

The analyzer is run so:

```
$ frama-c -val -machdep x86_32 t.c
```

And it produces:

```
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  t.c"
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
...
t.c:4:[kernel] warning: signed overflow. assert 0x7fffffff+1 ≤ 2147483647;
...
[value] Values at end of function main:
  NON TERMINATING FUNCTION
```

This means that the program t.c contains undefined behavior, and that no execution of it ever terminates without causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The two statements are not mutually incompatible.

- The standard does not define what behaviour each implementation is required to provide (so different implementations can do different things and still be standard conformant).
- Apple is allowed to define the behaviour of its implementation.

You as a programmer would be well advised to treat the behaviour as undefined since your code may need to be moved to other platforms where the behaviour is different, and perhaps because Apple could, in theory, change its mind in the future and still conform to the standard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple's also treats it as undefined and their docs are just crap...

Comment: In theory this is true and the two statements are not mutually exclusive but practically both gcc and clang heavily make optimizations assuming integer overflows are undefined behavior.

Comment: @R..: that Apple's documents leave something to be desired is, of course, another possibility.  I think it is still slightly relevant to point out that the standard and the implementation have different objectives and the statements are not automatically incompatible.

Comment: I agree that's worth pointing out the general principle that an implementation can provide definitions for something the standard leaves undefined, but I don't think Apple has an implementation that actually defines overflow behavior. As ouah said, clang optimizes based on signed overflow being undefined. So I think in this case the document is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code

```
void test(int mode)
{
  int32_t a = 0x12345678;
  int32_t b = mode ? a*0x10000 : a*0x10000LL;
  return b;
}
```

If this method is invoked with a `mode` value of zero, the code will compute the long long value 0x0000123456780000 and store it into `a`.  The behavior of this is fully defined by the C standard: if bit 31 of the result is clear, it will lop off all but the bottom 32 bits and store the resulting (positive) integer into `a`.  If bit 31 were set and the result were being stored to a 32-bit `int` rather than a variable of type `int32_t`, the implementation would have some latitude, but implementations are only allowed to define `int32_t` if they would perform such narrowing conversions according to the rules of two's-complement math.

If this method were invoked with a non-zero `mode` value, then the numerical computation would yield a result outside the range of the temporary expression value, and as such would cause Undefined Behavior.  While the rules dictate what should happen if a calculation performed on a longer type is stored into a shorter one, they do not indicate what should happen if calculations don't fit in the type with which they are performed.  A rather nasty gap in the standard (which should IMHO be plugged) occurs with:

```
uint16_t multiply(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
  return x*y;
}
```

For all combinations of `x` and `y` values where the Standard says anything about what this function should do, the Standard requires that it compute and return the product mod 65536.  If the Standard were to mandate that for all combinations of `x` and `y` values 0-65535 this method must return the arithmetical value of (x*y) mod 65536, it would be mandating behavior with which 99.99% of standards-compliant compilers would already be in conformance.  Unfortunately, on machines where `int` is 32 bits, the Standard presently imposes no requirements with regard to this function's behavior in cases where the arithmetical product would be larger than 2147483647.  Even though any portion of the intermediate result beyond the bottom 16 bits will ignored, the code will try to evaluate the result using a 32-bit signed integer type; the Standard imposes no requirements on what should happen if a compiler recognizes that the product will overflow that type.